# Cperl-mode syntax highlighting breaks when inserting a newline into a here doc

Tags: major-mode, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, string, perl

in `cperl-mode`, here docs are colored with a `font-lock-string-face`. However if you used any function that inserts a newline on a blank line (e.g. `M-: (insert "\n")`) it will cause all code after the newline to be highlighted with `font-lock-comment-face`. The only way to fix it is try and "mess with" here doc tags so that cperl re-parses and corrects the font-lock. I have a feeling this may have something to do with [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/why-does-inserting-a-newline-break-highlighting-with-syntax-propertize-function) issue since it is also dealing with multi-line syntax highlighting. Is there an expert out there who can help me find a way to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $here_doc = <<'_HERE_';
this is here doc line
<--- call (insert "\n") when cursor is here
_HERE_
```

Comment: That's a bug in `cperl-mode`.  I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug` (BTW, it's not just on empty lines: it seems to apply whenever you insert the newline at BOL).  In the mean time, you might like to use `perl-mode` which doesn't seem to suffer from this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually this bug has been fixed in the Emacs repository.  You can use [cperl-mode.el](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/progmodes/cperl-mode.el) directly from that repository with Emacs 26.1 or newer.

The fix does what could have been done in font-lock-extend-region-functions as suggested by wasamasa and now uses the same method as perl-mode.el to mark here-documents.

Answer (score 2):

The package [highlight-refontification](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-refontification) visualizes how font-lock refontifies a buffer. In this case, it starts at the line where the point is.

One way to handle this is to add a function to `font-lock-extend-region-functions` to expand the region to include the full heredoc comment.

One thing that is curious is that the highlighting becomes correct when pressing `return` but not when evaluating `(insert "\n")`, something I have no explanation for.

Comment: Hitting `RET` will run at the very least `newline` which does [a lot more](http://emacshorrors.com/posts/newline.html) than `(insert "\n")`, so this doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: How do I add my `font-lock-extend-region-function` that I wrote to the `font-lock-extend-region-functions`? Every example I could find was of someone creating a new major mode. There is no cperl specific hook.

Comment: You can use `(add-to-list 'font-lock-extend-region-functions #'my-extend-something)`. If can call this from a function in `cperl-mode-hook`.