# Cperl font lock regions in here docs

Tags: major-mode, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, string, perl

I am having a problem in `cperl-mode` described in [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/cperl-mode-syntax-highlighting-breaks-when-inserting-a-newline-into-a-here-doc) question. Basically inserting a newline at the start of a line in here doc in `cperl-mode` is breaking the syntax highlighting. One of the answers suggested using font-lock-extend-region-functions to extend the font lock region to include all of the here doc. I have done that with the code below and verified it with [highlight-refontification](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-refontification). However even though the region is extended, when I insert a newline, the region splits and the syntax highlighting still breaks. My function is shown below

```
(defun my/cperl-font-lock-extend-region-here ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char font-lock-beg)
    (if (re-search-backward "=<<\s*['\"]?[0-9a-zA-Z_]+['\"]?\s*;" nil t)
        (if (string-match "=<<\s*['\"]?\\([0-9a-zA-Z_]+\\)['\"]?\s*;" (thing-at-point 'line t))
            (let ((here-tag (concat "^" (match-string 1 (thing-at-point 'line t)) "$")))
              (beginning-of-line)
              (let ((here-start (point)))
                (goto-char font-lock-end)
                (if (re-search-forward here-tag nil t)
                    (progn
                      (end-of-line)
                      (if (< font-lock-end (point))
                          (setq font-lock-end (point)))))
                (if (> font-lock-beg here-start)
                    (setq font-lock-beg here-start))))))))
```

My question is, does any smart person know an approach to prevent syntax highlighting from breaking in `cperl-mode` here docs?